# dotnet core ubuntu is openning over 20k files

Tags: linux, nginx, .net-core, ubuntu-18.04, kestrel

I am running a dotnet core application behind nginx and I just found out that it is currently open more than 20k files by running this command

```
lsof | awk '{ print $2 " " $1; }' | sort -rn | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -20
```

Should I be worry about this? How can I reduce this number for better IO performance?

Comment: What version of .NET Core and did you enable any logging?

Comment: I am using dotnet core 2.1.6 with logging to 2 log files.